# Python's equivalent to C# Hash (#) in a format string

Tags: python

In C# and other languages, a hash (#) in the format string will be replaced by a number if one exists, and nothing if it doesn't. So a string such as:

```
number1 = 12.3456
number2 = 12.3
String.Format("0.00####", number1)
String.Format("0.00####", number2)
```

Will output `number1 = 12.3456` but `number2 = 12.30`. A zero in the format string means if there isn't enough decimal numbers, a zero will be printed out instead.

My question is, is there a similar functionality in Python? I know I can use "{:.6F}" to format a number to 6 decimal points.

Comment: As you already mentioned in your question you can use a format specifier in curly brackets. In addition to this there is a complete [Mini-Language for string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) which can be used with the [`string.format()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
print("{:0<.6f} {:0<.1f}".format(12.355, 0.12345))
```

Output:

```
12.355000 0.1
```

Comment: When i change it to `"{:0<1f}".format(12.355)`, I still get `12.355000`. **Update:** I think you missed a dot in the middle, should be `"{:0<.1f}".format(12.355)`

Comment: @MoatazElmasry, sure, thanks for the correction! i've updated the answer.

Comment: no worries, I've marked your answer as correct. Thanks a lot!